# Retrofit, set another value in a response model, based on a parsed value

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

So basically what I am wondering is it possible to set a value in a response model, based on another value parsed from JSON response, a the time the parsed value is set from Retrofit

Example response model

```
class UserModel {
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    var id: Int? = null
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    var name: String? = null
    @SerializedName("picture")
    @Expose
    var picture: String? = null
    @SerializedName("type")
    @Expose
    var type: int? = null
}
```

Example of what I want to achieve: Set another property called userType (String), for example if type == 1, set userType = "Admin"
What I tried

```
class UserModel {
    var userType: String? = null

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    var id: Int? = null
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    var name: String? = null
    @SerializedName("picture")
    @Expose
    var picture: String? = null
    @SerializedName("type")
    @Expose
    var type: int? = null
        set(value) {
                field = value
                if (value == 1) {
                    userType = "Admin"
                } else {
                    userType = "User"
                }
        }
}
```

But this does not work.
Any idea how to achieve this?

Cheers

**EDIT:** I managed to succeed with something like this

```
class UserModel {
    var userType: String? = null
        get() {
            if (type == 1) {
                field = "Admin"
            } else {
                field = "User"
            }
            return field
        }

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    var id: Int? = null
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    var name: String? = null
    @SerializedName("picture")
    @Expose
    var picture: String? = null
    @SerializedName("type")
    @Expose
    var type: int? = null
}
```

But does anyone have any better idea?

Comment: most likely this would need a custom retrofit DeSerializer, i'm assuming you need to send this value to the server or something similar, because otherwise you could consider a custom get, instead of a custom set ?

Comment: or, what you can do, is write a nice extension function, where you convert your api response to a local model and in there write the logic for what each value is based on the api's response, essentially the same as what a deserializer would achieve, but without having to know how to do it

Comment: @a_local_nobody tried custom getter. Same thing as custom setter, never gets called for some reason.

Comment: @a_local_nobody I have figured out a custom getter on the userTypeProperty solved it. Thanks for the idea. I am stupid sometimes :D

Comment: you're welcome, just to add, `@SerializedName("id")` isn't needed if your variable name is the same as the json you're receiving, so in your case, you could remove all of these if you wanted to remove some more code : )

Comment: @a_local_nobody yeah I know, this is not a realistic model, I just quickly copied an example from the web to show what I want to achieve.